# How can I add rails code to id attribute in div tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4

I would like to do something like this: `<div id="<%=service.name%>"`

However, I just can't get it to work. I need help! I am trying to create a modal for each button clicked on, but with just on modal div in html.erb.

For the modals to work they would need to be the same ID.

```
<% @services.each do |service| %>

<div class="card">
<a class="card-b" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="# <%=service.name%> ">
</div>

<div class="modal" id=" <%=service.name%> " tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
Hello this is the modal.
</div>

<% end %>
```

I would like to use rails code in the ID tag, I don't know if that is possible?

**EDIT:**

I tried the best answer and it worked only for a few of the modals and the rest didn't. Then I added a `modal_tag` column to my table and all the modals worked. Thank you!

My code is now `id="<%=service.modal_tag%>`

Comment: remove the spaces in `data-target` and `id`. Also for `id` to work the name would have to be unique otherwise as mentioned below use the database `id` instead (guaranteed to be unique). Also make sure you close the anchor tag

Comment: *"When specified on HTML elements, the id attribute value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element’s tree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters."* - [W3C HTML 5.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-id)

Answer (score 5):

My preference is to use a unique value like [`SecureRandom.hex`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) or [`__id__`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-__id__) as [`engineersmnky`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978251/engineersmnky) pointed out, instead of using model ids. Code would look something like this:

```
# You may also have to require 'securerandom' within your rails app 
# (can't remember if that comes in automatically or not)
<% @services.each do |service| %>
  <!-- Either option for random_id works below -->
  <% random_id = SecureRandom.hex %> 
  <% random_id = service.__id__ %>

  <div class="card">
    <a class="card-b" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<%= random_id %>">
  </div>

  <div class="modal" id="<%= random_id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-  hidden="true">
    Hello this is the modal.
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The reason I prefer this, is it doesn't leak database ids (if that's something you care about) and you're less likely to get id collisions in the event that this modal gets embedded into other pages.

---

And given a simple benchmarking script, it looks like `__id__` is the more performant of the two options:

```
$ cat unique_id.test.rb
require 'securerandom'
require 'benchmark'

n = 100_000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { n.times do |n|  ; SecureRandom.hex; end }
  x.report { n.times do |n|  ; n.__id__ ; end }
end

$ ruby unique_id.test.rb
   user     system      total        real
   0.180000   0.000000   0.180000 (  0.176293)
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.005554)
```

Comment: Why generate a `hex` then? `_service.__id__` will not leak a database id and is likely to be unique given that I doubt `Service` is an immutable interned object

Comment: @engineersmnky never thought to use the underlying object id. According to the docs: `no two active objects will share an id` so it would work just as well.

Comment: HTML ids must begin with a letter, just so you know. But you can easily add some sort of prefix such as “service-“ to the IDs you generate.

Comment: @Nate Not true. According to the [Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-id) *"The id attribute specifies its element’s unique identifier (ID).
There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc."*

Comment: @engineersmnky That’s only true as of HTML5. Before that, my statement is true. The OP did not specify whether they were using HTML4 or 5, so I commented. Also some articles will recommend you still start with a letter for backwards compatibility. Also, tossing a prefix in will help prevent collisions in IDs, which the OP was concerned about already.

Comment: @Nate You stated it as a universal fact that is why I commented. Also given that this question is tagged [tag:bootstrap-4] I think we can reasonably assume that HTML 4 spec is not a concern here.

Comment: @engineersmnky you’re right. I should have mentioned html 4 in my comment. I’m not familiar with bootstrap, so that tag meant nothing to me, rails did. It’s also worth noting that if this code is going to be used with ajax, this code *can* have collisions across servers. If there’s any pagination / infinite scroll features involved, it’s possible for the ruby object ids to collide across servers. So, you should really clarify these caveats in your answer, lest someone who also doesn’t care about bootstrap or maybe uses older bootstrap read your answer and have issues. Completeness is good.

Comment: @Nate very well. **Caveat**: if you plan on using `__id__` AND you plan on loading this data in an asynchronous manner AND you have an extremely large number of elements THEN there is a slight possibility of causing a collision. I tested this theory over 40_000 ids trying a maximum of 5_000 times per each id to cause a collision (so max iterations 200_000_000). This test was run 10 times and the collision rate was ~ 0.001% - 0.003%.

Comment: @engineersmnky The collision rate is definitely low for sure. I just feel it’s important to point out. This is the kind of thing that’ll break once a year for someone, and a bug will be reported, and it’ll be nearly impossible to reproduce, and a bunch of time will be wasted on something trivial. That’s why I’m bringing this up. Random and unique are two different things. Random works well enough *most* times.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby on Rails has a [`dom_id` method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RecordIdentifier.html#method-i-dom_id) to generate unique ids for the use in HTML documents. Furthermore, I do not like to mix HTML tags and ERB – therefore I would probably work with a helper method

```
# in a helper
def service_modal(service, &block)
  tag.div(class: 'card') do
    tag.a(class: 'card-b', data: {toggle: 'modal', target: dom_id(service) }, href: '#')
  end +

  tag.div(class: 'modal', dom_id(service), tabindex: 1, role: 'dialog', 'aria-hidden': 'true') do
    capture(&block)
  end
end
```

and use it like this

```
# in the view
<% @services.each do |service| %>
  <%= service_modal(service) do %>
    Hello this is the modal.
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I was completely unaware of the `dom_id` method. Nice to learn a new trick.

Comment: TIL! This is a good solution too. It will leak database identifiers but for most use cases would be the most appropriate.

Comment: @GavinMiller that it true. But this should not be an issue because Rails per default leaks database identifiers in URLs anyway. If you use a gem like friendly_id or override the to_param method yourself to avoid this behavior then you should consider overriding to_key too.

Answer (score 0):

Also, You can use `object_id`.

**Rails:** `data-target="#<%= service.object_id %>">`

Benchmark:

```
   user     system      total        real
0.071505   0.000187   0.071692 (  0.072017) #SecureRandom.hex
0.004685   0.000016   0.004701 (  0.004727) #__id__
0.004500   0.000001   0.004501 (  0.004503) #object_id
```

Comment: Benchmarks might be a bit misleading since `__id__` and `object_id` are aliases for the same internal call